# HTML title appears in italics for unknown reasons

Tags: html, title, italics

The title on my page keeps showing up in italics and I can't find any code indicating that it should do so.  What could be going on?  I have even copy/pasted header code from another page where the title was not italicized but it still persists.

```
    <head>
<title>1867 Settlement - Origins</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    background-color: #E6E6FA;
}
.style2 {
    font-size: small;
    font-style: italic;
}
.style3 {font-size: small}
a:link {
    color: #B2243B;
}
a:visited {
    color: #B2243B;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean here with "title"? That `<title>` tags shown in your code lines is _not_ shown on the web page. It is meta information only, mostly for search robots. Some browsers also display it in the window top bar. But a visible title on the web page itself has to be in the `<body>` section of the markup.

Comment: By title, I mean exactly what title sounds like: some text that appears at the top of my page with the name of the page.  The code around the actual title has nothing about the font being in italics.  The *only* thing in the whole webpage that has anything about italic is what I just posted from <head>, but only the title itself is showing up in italics.  The rest of the text is regular.

Comment: Well, there has to be some rule, the browser does not do that by itself. Right click in the element and expect it.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to style the title attribute quite easily using the content property

```
a[title]:hover:after {
 content: attr(title);
 padding: 4px 8px;
 color: #333;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 100%;
 z-index: 20;
 white-space: nowrap;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #222;
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left    bottom,color-stop(0, #eeeeee),color-stop(1, #cccccc));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
  }
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/tDQWN/